# how to bind date in Line series chart x axis windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In line series chart I want to show date by binding it on  x axis and on y axis the index start from 90 
I am using WCF method to access date

### .xaml code

```
<Charting:Chart Name="MyChart" Title="" Margin="11,153,-2,39">  
<Charting:LineSeries Margin="0" IndependentValuePath="Item1"   
 DependentValuePath="Item2" IsSelectionEnabled="True" Title="Blood Glucose" 
 Foreground="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding Measurement}" />
</Charting:Chart>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
        string result = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "getbg1?Email=" + 
        emailtxtbox.Text + "");
        result = result.Replace("{\"getbg1Result\":", "");
        result = result.Replace("]}", "]");
        List<BG> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BG>>(result);
        int item1 = 0;
        int item2 = 1;
        int item3 = 2;
        string a1 = "";
        string b2 = "";
        string c3 = "";
        foreach (BG b in data)
        {
             item1 = b.Measurement[0];
             item2 = b.Measurement[1];
             item3 = b.Measurement[2];
                a1 = b.Date_[0].ToString();
                b2 = b.Date_[1].ToString();
                c3 = b.Date_[2].ToString();
        }

        List<Tuple<string, int>> myList = new List<Tuple<string, int>>()
        {

            new Tuple<string, int>(a1, item1),
            new Tuple<string, int>(b2, item2),
            new Tuple<string, int>(c3, item3)                

    };

        (MyChart.Series[0] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = myList;
       }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue by doing these lines of code

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string result = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "getbg1?Email=" +   
                                                    emailtxtbox.Text + "");
        result = result.Replace("{\"getbg1Result\":", "");
        result = result.Replace("]}", "]");
        List<BG> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BG>>(result);
        int item1 = 0;
        int item2 = 1;
        int item3 = 2;
        int item4 = 0;

        item1 =int.Parse( data[0].Measurement);
        item2 = int.Parse(data[1].Measurement);
        item3 = int.Parse(data[2].Measurement);


        List<Tuple<string, int>> myList = new List<Tuple<string, int>>()
        {


            new Tuple<string, int>(data[0].Date_, item1),
            new Tuple<string, int>(data[1].Date_, item2),
            new Tuple<string, int>(data[2].Date_, item3),            
        };

        (MyChart.Series[0] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = myList;



    }
```